# SQLAlchemy MySQL STRAIGHT_JOIN

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy

My code currently executes queries just fine in the SQLAlchemy ORM layer like so:

```
session().query(model_a).join(
    (model_b, something == somethingelse)
).join(
    (model_c, something == somethingelse)
) # etc ...
```

But I've come across a query that was taking minutes to finish. Turns out MySQL is to blame because it's not joining in the order we ask it to. Adding `STRAIGHT_JOIN` after `SELECT` like:

```
SELECT STRAIGHT_JOIN table_a.id FROM table_a INNER JOIN table_b ...
```

Fixes the problem but I can't figure out if there's a way to make SQLAlchemy add `STRAIGHT_JOIN` after `SELECT`. The docs suggest that hints can be added to `select()` via `with_hint(table_a, "STRAIGHT_JOIN")` but this adds the text in the wrong place which causes a MySQL syntax error. This would also involve stepping outside of the ORM which is not ideal.

I've tried using the various MySQL debugging techniques like `EXPLAIN`, `ANALYZE TABLE` etc... but can't seem to find out why MySQL is choosing the wrong path. Manually switching around the order of the joins doesn't seem to help either so I'm now in a position where I need to get STRAIGHT_JOIN to work.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

we support this directly just for the case of MySQL and their strange keywords:

```
session().query(model_a).prefix_with("STRAIGHT_JOIN").join(
    (model_b, something == somethingelse)
).join(
    (model_c, something == somethingelse)
) # etc ...
```

http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_8/orm/query.html?highlight=query.prefix_with#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.prefix_with